# Convert a List[(String, String)] to List[Map[String, String]] in scala

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, tuples, gatling

I am using Gatling and want to use feeders. Apparently, feeders require a `List[Map[String, String]]`. I have a list of tuples like

```
{("key", "abcde"),("key", "bcdef")...}
```

and I want to convert it into

```
{ Map("key", "abcde"), Map("key", "bcdef")...}
```

How can I do that? I am new to Scala programming and would appreciate any help here.

Comment: It's impossible to have duplicate keys in map.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val tupleList = List(("key", "abcde"),("key",           "bcdef"))                                                              
val mapList = tupleList map { case (k,v) => Map(k-> v)}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```scala
val x: List[(String, String)] = List(("key", "abcde"),("key", "bcdef"))
val y: List[Map[String, String]] = x.map(p => Map(p._1 -> p._2))
```

since you are creating new Map for every tuple so duplicate key should not be an issue as suggested in comments